# Unable to see 10 million char length Request Payload in Chrome Network tab for

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-chrome

I'm using Mac (v 10.13) . When I open up my Chrome devtools, go to an XHR request, and click on the Headers, I only see these two things for application/JSON request for JSON payload which is greater than 10 million characters:
I am sending data with angular $http() post method.

When I send the JSON request with length less than 10million char's in length, the request payload is showing as shown in the below image.

[image]

But when we send the JSON request with length greater than 10 million char's in length, the request payload is not showing at all as show in below image.[image]

Please help me to figure out what is the actual mistake i am doing, whether it is a Javascript issue or chrome issue.?

Comment: Whats the size of the file being uploaded?

Comment: @magneticmagnum It is a more than 10 million characters string (more than  10MB) which I am sending in request payload as a JSON. I am not uploading any file.

Comment: Ah, I assumed (and made an ass out of myself) that it would be a file when I saw the title and thought it was a filename.

Comment: Can you post code examples of how your `post` code looks like?

Comment: Still thinking about this issue during my commute to / from work;  I decided to try and replicate your issue and cannot.  In Chrome, I am able to see the entire 10 million character string using the following code run in the console:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'google.com', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: a
}));

and set var a = {10MillionCharacterString}

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate the issue using pure javascript.

I'll put the code in jsbin since a 10 million character string doesn't look good on StackOverflow:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", 'google.com', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: tenMilCharString
}));
```

Jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/fatigahufo/edit?js